# Macro syntax-case match list

Tags: racket

I am trying to create macro, that from input list generates some code. But I can't match it in my syntax-case.

Example code:

```
#lang racket/base

(require (for-syntax racket/base))


(define test-data '(root
                     ()
                     (branch ((name "left")) (leaf ((name "green0"))) (leaf ((name "yellow"))) (leaf ((name "pink"))))
                     (branch ((name "right")) (leaf ((name "name2"))))
  (branch ((name "broken")))))

(define-syntax (parse-xml stx)
  (syntax-case stx (root branch)
    [(_ (root () branches ...))
     #'branches...
     ]
    [(_ rest) #'rest]))

(parse-xml  (datum->syntax #'() test-data))
```

I feel that I am missing something very basic, but I can't find out how to "expand" input parameter into stx to be matchable. Could you please help me with it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you help a little bit with what you want? The way you have it right now, `parse-xml` is a macro, operating at compile time, but the value of `test-data` is only known at run time. Do you want to parse the xml stuff at compile time, or do you just need it at run time?

Comment: I need to resd .xml file and generate dbus interface out of it: https://docs.racket-lang.org/dbus/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._dbus%2Fmain..rkt%29._define-dbus-interface%29%29 So I guess that .xml file should be resd also in compile time if it is possible.

Comment: Okay. How would a "user" use `parse-xml` then? That affects how the macro should be written.

Comment: this should be "helper" fun but I expect user to call st. like (generate-dbus-interface "org.freedesktop.Notifications.xml") xml describes format of dbus messages (https://github.com/abranson/rockpool/blob/master/rockwork/org.freedesktop.Notifications.xml) from that should be  generated exactly this source code: `(define-dbus-interface notifications<%> "org.freedesktop.Notifications"
      (CloseNotification "u")
      (GetCapabilities "")
      (GetServerInformation "")
      (Notify "susssasa{sv}i"))` That means parse it get method names and types, join types to string and output interfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you want to parse it at run time

You don't need `parse-xml` to be a macro, it can just be a normal function. This means two changes.

1. Change the `define-syntax` back into `define`
2. Change the function to account for it receiving just the xml stuff, not the entire "macro" expression.

Changing both of these results in

```
(define (parse-xml xml)
  (syntax-case xml (root branch)
    [(root () branches ...)         ; notice how the pattern changed for (2)
     #'branches...
     ]
    [rest #'rest]))
```

The body is unfinished, I assume you can take it from here.

#### If you want to parse it at compile time

According to your comments, a user would use it like this:

```
(parse-xml/file "path/to/data.xml")
```

Then the macro shouldn't take a variable like `test-data`, it should take a file path.

```
(require (for-syntax racket/base))

(define-syntax parse-xml/file
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ file-path)
       ....
       ])))
```

The next thing to do is find the file to read. The best way I've found for resolving a path for a macro is `resolve-path-spec` from `syntax/path-spec`.

```
(require (for-syntax racket/base
                     syntax/path-spec))

(define-syntax parse-xml/file
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ file-path)
       (.... (resolve-path-spec #'file-path #'file-path stx) ....)])))
```

The next step is reading from it, probably using `open-input-file` and `syntax:read-xml` from `xml`.

```
(require (for-syntax racket/base
                     syntax/path-spec
                     xml))

(define-syntax parse-xml/file
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ file-path)
       (....
        (syntax:read-xml
         (open-input-file (resolve-path-spec #'file-path #'file-path stx)))
        ....)])))
```

At this point, you have a syntax object, produced by `syntax:read-xml`, containing the data.

Now we can use the function back from the ***If you want to parse it at run time*** section. To use it at compile time, just put the definition in a `begin-for-syntax`.

```
(require (for-syntax racket/base
                     syntax/path-spec
                     xml))

(begin-for-syntax
  (define (parse-xml xml)
    (syntax-case (xml->xexpr
                  ((eliminate-whitespace '(root branch name leaf))
                   (document-element xml))) (root branch)
      [(root () branches ...)
       #''(branches ...)
       ]
      [rest #'rest])))

(define-syntax parse-xml/file
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ file-path)
       (parse-xml
           (read-xml
            (open-input-file (resolve-path-spec #'file-path #'file-path stx))))
       ])))
```

All that's left is finishing the *function* version of `parse-xml` to parse it and generate the code.

Comment: Here is a working example of notification sending: https://gist.github.com/Ondra09/ec439223b8ceea887e32dedea211c7e3  I would love to have lines 11-15 autogenerated according to this xml: https://github.com/abranson/rockpool/blob/master/rockwork/org.freedesktop.Notifications.xml

Comment: Thank you a lot Alex, your answer was very helpful.